# Trouble with scheduling weekly notifications SWIFT

Tags: swift

I am having a problem with scheduling notifications to go off every week. My question is what should the notification.repeatInterval equal for it to work. Thanks!

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)
{

    let state = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("notifications_enabled");

    if (!state) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    }
    else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        for var x = 2; x <= 3; x = x+1
        {
            createAlert(7, minute: 55, day: x, period: "Period 1 Starts in 5 Minutes");
            createAlert(8, minute: 45, day: x, period: "Period 2 Starts in 5 Minutes");
            createAlert(9, minute: 30, day: x, period: "Break Has Started");
            createAlert(10, minute: 10, day: x, period: "Period 3 Starts in 5 Minutes");
            createAlert(11, minute: 00, day: x, period: "Period 4 Starts in 5 Minutes");
            createAlert(11, minute: 50, day: x, period: "Period 5 Starts in 5 Minutes");
            createAlert(12, minute: 40, day: x, period: "Lunch Has Started");
            createAlert(13, minute: 51, day: x, period: "Period 6 Starts in 5 Minutes");
            createAlert(14, minute: 00, day: x, period: "Period 7 Starts in 5 Minutes");
            createAlert(14, minute: 50, day: x, period: "Period 8 Starts in 5 Minutes");
        }
    }

}

func createAlert(hour:Int, minute:Int, day:Int, period:String)
{
    let dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComp.hour = hour;
    dateComp.minute = minute;
    dateComp.weekday = day;
    dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    let calender:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let date:NSDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!

    let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

    notification.category = "Daily Quote"
    notification.alertBody = period
    notification.alertAction = "view"
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.soundName = "dingdongloud.mp3"
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit;

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification);
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` calendar unit?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is:

`notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.weekOfYear`

Because `NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit` was deprecated in iOS 8.0.

If You want to find the correct week of this year you can do the following

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.WeekOfYear, fromDate: date)
print(components.weekOfYear)
```

> 22 (for the day of the answer)

And if for some reason you want to cast this value to `NSCalendarUnit` do the following:

```
let week = UInt(components.weekOfYear)
NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: week)
```

Note: `NSCalendarUnit.weekOfYear.rawValue` will give you a **bitmask** of the week of year.

> 8192 (for the day of the answer)

Comment: I get the error message, "Cannot assign value of type int to type NSCalendarUnit"

Comment: The line `components.weekOfYear` will return the week in the current year as  `Int`. You can save that value, and only if the week is changed, post your notification.

Comment: Did you try `notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.weekOfYear`?

Comment: Type "NSCalendarUnit" has no member "weekOfYear"  .WeekOfYear runs, but notifications dont work